# Binary search tree implementation with Rule of Three

Tags: c++, tree

I started to code in C++ and tried to implement a simple BST data structure. Since at the moment I am learning about the Rule of Three, I tried to implement it in my code. Yet, I realize that my code might be far from efficient. I also doubt whether I've made a right destructor or not.

What are the best practices to use the Rule of Three, especially in this particular implementation (BST)? I would really open for any comments and suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Tree{
private:
    struct TreeNode{
        T data;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;

        TreeNode(T val):data(val),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
        //~TreeNode(){
        //    delete left;
        //    delete right;
        //}
    };

    TreeNode *root;
    void printHelper(TreeNode *)const;
    void insertHelper(T data, TreeNode *leaf);
    void DeleteHelper(T data, TreeNode* &);
    void DeleteNode(TreeNode* &);
    bool searchElementHelper(T key, TreeNode *leaf);
    void copyTree(TreeNode *&thisRoot, TreeNode *rhsRoot);
    TreeNode* findSmallest(TreeNode *,TreeNode *&);
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    Tree(const Tree& rhs);
    const Tree& operator=(const Tree& rhs);
    void insert(T);
    void Delete(T);
    void print()const;
    bool searchElement(T _data);
};

template<class T>
Tree<T>::Tree():root(NULL){}

template<class T>
Tree<T>::Tree(const Tree& rhs){
    if(rhs.root==NULL)
        root=NULL;
    else
        copyTree(root,rhs.root);
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::copyTree(TreeNode *&thisRoot,TreeNode *rhsRoot){
    if(rhsRoot==NULL)
        thisRoot=NULL;
    else{
        thisRoot = new TreeNode(rhsRoot->data);
        copyTree(thisRoot->left,rhsRoot->left);
        copyTree(thisRoot->right,rhsRoot->right);
    }
}

template<class T>
const Tree<T>& Tree<T>::operator=(const Tree& rhs){
    if(this!=&rhs){
        copyTree(this->root,rhs.root);
    }
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
Tree<T>::~Tree(){
    delete root;
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::insert(T _data){
    if(root==NULL)
        root = new TreeNode(_data);
    else{
        insertHelper(_data, root);
    }
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::insertHelper(T data, TreeNode *leaf){
    if(data < leaf->data){
        if(leaf->left == NULL){
            TreeNode *newNode = new TreeNode(data);
            leaf->left = newNode;
        }else
            insertHelper(data,leaf->left);
    }else if(data > leaf->data){
        if(leaf->right==NULL){
            TreeNode *newNode = new TreeNode(data);
            leaf->right = newNode;
            return;
        }
        insertHelper(data,leaf->right);
    }else{
        std::cout << "The data already exist" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::Delete(T _data){
    if(root==NULL){
        std::cout <<"The Tree is empty\n";
        return;
    }
    DeleteHelper(_data,root);
}
template<class T>
void Tree<T>::DeleteHelper(T _data,TreeNode* &rootRef){
    if(rootRef==NULL)
        return;
    if(_data==rootRef->data)
        DeleteNode(rootRef);
    else if(_data < rootRef->data)
        DeleteHelper(_data,rootRef->left);
    else if(_data > rootRef->data)
        DeleteHelper(_data,rootRef->right);
}
template<class T>
void Tree<T>::DeleteNode(TreeNode* &rootRef){
    // The current node has no children
    TreeNode* temp = rootRef;
    if(rootRef->left==NULL && rootRef->right==NULL)
        rootRef = NULL;
    else if(rootRef->left==NULL && rootRef->right!=NULL)
        rootRef = rootRef->right;
    else if(rootRef->left!=NULL && rootRef->right==NULL)
        rootRef = rootRef->left;
    else{ //current node has two childreen
        //find the smallest element in the right subtree
        TreeNode* parent = rootRef;
        temp = rootRef->right;
        temp = findSmallest(temp,parent);
        rootRef->data = temp->data;
        if(parent==rootRef)
            parent->right = temp->right;
        else
            parent->left = temp->left;
    }
    delete temp;
}

template<class T>
typename Tree<T>::TreeNode* Tree<T>::findSmallest(TreeNode *root, TreeNode *&parent){
    if(root->left==nullptr)
        return root;
    return findSmallest(root->left,root);
}
template<class T>
void Tree<T>::print()const{
    if(root==NULL)
        std::cout << "The Tree has no element" << std::endl;
    else
        printHelper(root);
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::printHelper(TreeNode *root)const{
     if(root==NULL)
         return;
    printHelper(root->left);
    std::cout << root->data << " " << std::endl;
    printHelper(root->right);
}

template<class T>
bool Tree<T>::searchElement(T _data){
    return searchElementHelper(_data,root);
}

template<class T>
bool Tree<T>::searchElementHelper(T _data,TreeNode *rootRef){
    if(rootRef==NULL)
        return false;
    if(_data==rootRef->data)
        return true;
    if(_data < rootRef->data)
        return searchElementHelper(_data,rootRef->left);
    if(_data > rootRef->data)
        return searchElementHelper(_data,rootRef->right);
    return false;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Tree<int> tree;
    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(19);
    tree.insert(11);
    tree.insert(16);
    tree.insert(13);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(14);
    tree.Delete(16);
    if(tree.searchElement(16))
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NOT Found" << std::endl;
    tree.print();
    Tree<int> tree2 = tree;
    std::cout<<"The elements of Tree 2: \n";
    tree2.print();

    Tree<int> tree3;
    tree3 = tree2;
    std::cout <<"The elements of Tree 3: \n";
    tree3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you deliberately decided not to use c++11 features? If so, why did you tag it with c++11?

Comment: And why did you comment out the destructor?

Comment: @MikeMB, thanks for your responds. Firstly, honestly, I want to use c++11 features but haven't tried it. I will edit my tag post. For the destructor, I just not sure about it that is why i commented it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time for a real review at the moment. But I'd recommend reading about smart pointers (especially `std::unique_ptr`) and applying them to your class. At a glance, it seems as if you have some memory leaks that could easily be prevented that way (as a first order of approximation: Don't use `new` in c++14 and beyond, but `make_unique` and `make_shared` instead). Also since c++11, the "Rule of 3/4/5/0" concep has become pretty useless in my opinion. You e.g. often don't need a destructor anymore.

Comment: One remark: While implementing a binary tree with dynamic allocation of nodes is a good programming exercise, binary search data structures can be implemented in a much much more efficient manner by packing everything in an array / std::vector (instead of allocating each node independently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a couple of remarks. Generally speaking, I will try to add tags such as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) before each so that you know which version you need for which improvement. If there isn't a tag, assume that it works with C++03:

- [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` to represent null pointers. It is safer since it avoids some problems: for example, if a function `foo` has an `int` overload and a `char*` overload, `foo(NULL)` will pick the `int` overload while `foo(nullptr)` will pick the `char*` overload, which is probaby what you would expect.
- You have some bugs. For example, the fact that you wrote a destructor for `TreeNode` but commented it out clearly highlights that there is a problem in your code (for example, it leaks memory since you never `delete` it properly). And indeed there is a problem: if we uncomment it, it shows that the `Delete` function frees memory where it shouldn't. It means that you have a bug somewhere in your `Delete` algorithm. But where?

  The answer is that when you perform `delete temp;` in `DeleteNode`, `temp` still refers to the old root and since you just assigned it one of its children, it also deletes the children while deleting the old root. Therefore, you need to assign `nullptr` to the old root's `left` and `right` fields before deleting it:

  ```
  temp->right = nullptr;
  temp->left = nullptr;
  delete temp;
  ```

  Now you can uncomment `TreeNode`'s destructor and enjoy a correct code without memory leaks.
- [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) Consider adding a move constructor and a move assignment operator to your class. The cost of moving a tree is trivial compared to what it costs to copy a whole tree:

  ```
  template<class T>
  Tree<T>::Tree(Tree&& other):
      root(other.root)
  {
      other.root = nullptr;
  }
  ```

  See, all the move constructor does is acquire the memory managed by `other` and assign `nullptr` to `other.root` so that the memory does not get freed when `other` is destructed.
- `const`-correctness is important in C++. When one of your methods does not modify a class, mark it `const`. Not only will it make it clear which functions modify the class and which ones do not, but it is also essential if you need to use these functions in a `const` context.

  ```
  bool searchElementHelper(T key, TreeNode *leaf) const;
                                                  ^^^^^
  ```
- Use more spaces, for example, around the operators. As of right now, your code looks a bit like a big "block" and could use a bit more space to breath.
- Also, be consistent when naming your functions. I know that you can't use `delete` as a method name since it's a keyword, but in this case look for a synonym such as `remove` or `erase` (the second one would be consistent with the names used in the standard library). Consistency is the key to usability and maintainability.
- Speaking of consistency, it's good practice to always use curly braces with flow control statements, even if there is only one statement between the curly braces. Not only does it make it easier to add more statements later, but it also prevents stupid mistakes such as [Apple's `goto fail` bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) that can go unnoticed and wreak havoc in your program.
- You don't need to `return 0;` at the end of `main`: the compiler will do it for you if it doesn't encounter any `return` statement. That behaviour is often used as a way to document that your `main` cannot return anything else than `0`.
- I would expect a `searchElement` method to return at least an `iterator` or a pointer of some kind to the searched element. To avoid confusion, a better name for the method you wrote would be `contains`.
- You might want a better separation of responsibilities between `Tree` and `TreeNode`. For example, here is how I would rewrite the `contains` method, letting `TreeNode` handle more things:

  ```
  template<class T>
  bool Tree<T>::contains(T value) const {
      if (root == nullptr) {
          return false;
      }
      return root->contains(value);
  }

  template<class T>
  bool Tree<T>::TreeNode::contains(T value) const {
      if (value == data) {
          return true;
      }
      if (value < data) {
          return left && left->contains(value);
      }
      if (value > data) {
          return right && right->contains(value);
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

  I find this code easier to reason about since, once in `TreeNode::contains`, it is clear that we will only deal with `data`, `left` and `right` and nothing else besides the function's parameters. It lessens the cognitive effort for the reader.
- By the way, you could reduce redundancy in naming by renaming `Tree::TreeNode` into `Tree::Node`. Since it's an inner class, you already have the information that it is a `Tree` node from the enclosing class name.

Comment: Thank you so much @Morwenn, I really appreciate your feedback. Indeed, there are some bugs in my node removal algorithm, and now it works like charm. However, I have a question about defining a function as a const function. Why it is necessary to define for instance in my implementation searchElementHelper as constant? well, I understand about it gives clearer information which one will modify and which one not. But can you give more specific example, like in a real project? Thanks

Comment: @user2997327 Making `const` methods allows you to use them on a `const Tree<int>`. For example, if a function is a declared as `void foobar(const Tree<int>& tree)`, it can still call `tree.searchElement` while it wouldn't be possible if `searchElement` wasn't marked as `const`.